# Firebase Data passing between table view and Navigation view

Tags: swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get the data from the cell that I clicked to a navigation controller. (And then the data in label. I want A sort of extra information tab) This is what I got so far:

This is mij Post class:

```
class Post {
    let ref: DatabaseReference!
    var TypeControle: String = ""
    var Stad: String = ""
    var Tijd: String = ""
    var Latitude: String = ""
    var Longitude: String = ""
    var Extrainformatie: String = ""

    init(TypeControle: String) {
        self.TypeControle = TypeControle
        ref = Database.database().reference().child("Rollerbanken").childByAutoId()
    }
    init(Stad: String){
        self.Stad = Stad
        ref = Database.database().reference().child("Rollerbanken").childByAutoId()
    }
    init(Tijd: String) {
        self.Tijd = Tijd
        ref = Database.database().reference().child("Rollerbanken").childByAutoId()
    }
    init(Latitude: String) {
        self.Latitude = Latitude
        ref = Database.database().reference().child("Rollerbanken").childByAutoId()
    }
    init(Longitude: String) {
        self.Longitude = Longitude
        ref = Database.database().reference().child("Rollerbanken").childByAutoId()
    }
    init(Extrainformatie: String) {
        self.Extrainformatie = Extrainformatie
        ref = Database.database().reference().child("Rollerbanken").childByAutoId()
    }

    init() {
        ref = Database.database().reference().child("Rollerbanken").childByAutoId()
    }

    init(snapshot: DataSnapshot)
    {
        ref = snapshot.ref
        if let value = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] {
            TypeControle = value["TypeControle"] as! String
            Stad = value["Stad"] as! String
            Tijd = value["Tijd"] as! String
            Latitude = value["Latitude"] as! String
            Longitude = value["Longitude"] as! String
            Extrainformatie = value["Extrainformatie"] as! String

        }
    }

    func save() {
        ref.setValue(toDictionary())
    }

    func toDictionary() -> [String : Any]
    {
        return [
            "TypeControle" : TypeControle,
            "Stad" : Stad,
            "Tijd" : Tijd,
            "Latitude" : Latitude,
            "Longitude" : Longitude,
            "Extrainformatie" : Extrainformatie
        ]
    }
}
```

Database Structure:
[image: Structure]

TableviewCell:
[image]

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "mySegue" {
            if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let controller = segue.destination as! ExtraViewController
                let story = posts[indexPath.row]
                controller.tijd = story["Tijd"] as! String
            }
    }
}
```

The error that I get is:    Type 'Post' has no subscript members.

On line: `controller.tijd = story["Tijd"] as! String`

Comment: share you posts values screen shot.

Comment: i have updated it

Comment: How did you declare your posts array ? :)

Answer (score 0):

try this  :-

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
      if segue.identifier == "mySegue" {
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let controller = segue.destination as! ExtraViewController
            let story = posts[indexPath.row]
             print(story.Tijd)
            controller.tijd = story.Tijd as! String
        }
  }
}
```

in ExtraViewController:-

```
var tijd:String!
```

i think your array contains post model  class type objects.

Comment: It doesnt work, the data wont go to "ExtraViewController". I dont understand why

Comment: check once you are not setting any value in  tijd  in ExtraViewController. and also print(story.Tijd) to check value is not empty.

Comment: There isnt a value. If i print `print("test \(Tijd)")` says the consol: "test nil".

Comment: Can you please help?

Comment: please debug once again and let me know value of story.Tijd.

Answer (score 0):

The error that you get gives us an hint of what the problem is :

```
Type 'Post' has no subscript members
```

Here `story` ( in `story = posts[indexPath.row]`) is of type Post, and Post doesn't have a subscript defined in its class scope. Which is why when you try to write `story["Tijd"]` it throws an error.

From what I can see, I believe you should do an optional type cast `as? [String : AnyObject]` of your snapshot when you receive it, but I'm not sure to understand how you init your snapshot.